# How to generate random data from pareto density function in R?

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to generate data from given pareto density in R.

Pareto density: F(x) = |X|^(-3) * 1  |x|>1

I know that I need to use rpareto function from actuar library, but I am not sure how should I transform given pareto density into parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Using inverse sampling method, formulas from [Pareto Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution)

Here is updated version with mean and sd computed

```
rpar <- function(n, xm, a) {
    v <- runif(n)
    xm / v^(1.0/a)
}

rpar_mean <- function(xm, a) {
    result <- 1/0 # Inf
    if (a > 1.0)
        result <- a*xm/(a - 1.0)
    result
}

rpar_var <- function(xm, a) {
    result <- 1/0 # Inf
    if (a > 2.0)
        result <- xm*xm*a/((a - 1.0)^2*(a - 2.0))
    result
}

set.seed(54122345)

xm = 1.0
a  = 3.0

q <- rpar(10000, xm, a)
print(mean(q))
print(rpar_mean(xm, a))

print(sd(q))
print(sqrt(rpar_var(xm, a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pareto distribution is simple enough to allow for the transformation method (aka [Inverse Transform Sampling](https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/inverse_transform_sampling.html)). The CDF of the Pareto distribution is

$$F(x) = \int_{x_{min}}^x f(x')\,dx' = 1- \left(\frac{x_{min}}{x}\right^k$$

which can be analytically inverted to

$$F^{-1}(y) = x_{min} \cdot (1-y)^{-1/k}$$

Thus, if you transform random numbers uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ with $F^{-1}$, you obtain Pareto distributed random numbers.

**Edit:** Oh sorry, apparently Latex-Code is not supported here. Here is, for your convenince, the R code:

```
k <- 5      # parameter k of the Pareto distribution
x.min <- 2  # cutoff point of Pareto distribution
N <- 500    # number of random points
x.random <- x.min*(1-runif(N))^(-1/k)
```

And here is the practical demonstration that it works:

```
h <- hist(x.random, freq=FALSE, plot=TRUE)
x <- seq(x.min, h$breaks[length(h$breaks)], by=0.01)
lines(x, k*x.min^k/x^(k+1), col="red")
```

[plot for k=5 and x.min=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLzLI.png)

Comment: You could save some time as I did: 1-U(0,1) is distributed in the same way as U(0,1)

Comment: @Severin Pappadeux
Yes, indeed.