# Fit pareto distribution on amounts

Tags: r, distribution

I want to fit a Pareto distribution on a list of amounts (10 amounts from $400K to $10M).
But I notice that the mean formula doesn't seem to work for large numbers? I don't see where I'm making a mistake.

**Test OK**: the empirical mean is near the theoretical value

```r
> ashape <- 2
> ascale <- 3
> test <- VGAM::rpareto(10000000,  shape=ashape, scale=ascale)
> mean(test)
[1] 5.995407
> (ascale*ashape)/(ashape-1)
[1] 6
```

**Test KO**: the empirical mean (3.38 M) is lower than the theorical value (4.5M)

```r
> ashape <- 1.097560976
> ascale <- 400000
> test <- VGAM::rpareto(10000000,  shape=ashape, scale=ascale)
> mean(test)
[1] 3378307
> (ascale*ashape)/(ashape-1)
[1] 4500000
```

How am I supposed to fit big numbers with a Pareto Distribution?

Comment: Welcome. Please take a moment to read the [Markdown format editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help); and please don’t repeat tags in the question title.

Comment: Sorry! thank you for the link. I saw blockquotes tag but everything was put on a single line  so i remove it :(

Comment: With some quick test, the issue occurs when shape parameter is close to 1. Try a bigger shape parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

I thought problem is with the summation, and tried Kaham sum, no difference

Even home made paretto sampler (see [How to generate random data from pareto density function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913996/how-to-generate-random-data-from-pareto-density-function-in-r)) has the same problem.

Puzzled